# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `SQL query` which selects some values (and works across tables in the form of a join). One of the fields returns 0 or 1 but I want to return something else in the case of 0, or the case of 1 (yes/no).

The code:

```
SELECT Passed, 
       CASE Passed
            WHEN '1' THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END
FROM EXAM_INSTANCE
```

Works perfectly well.

But when I integrate this as a sub-query in the stored proc, I get the error:

`Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the sub-query is not introduced with EXISTS.`

The original query is:

```
select Firstname, Lastname, ei.Started, 
       ((ei.totalcorrect*100)/@examQuestionCount) as percentage, passed, ei.InstanceID
from ea ei, INVITE i, OSTTable ost, f f
where ei.Finished is not null
      and ei.InviteID = i.InviteID
```

I am trying:

```
   select Firstname, Lastname, ei.Started, 
          ((ei.totalcorrect*100)/@examQuestionCount) as percentage, 
   (SELECT Passed, 
           CASE Passed
                WHEN '1' THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No'
           END
     FROM EA), 
     ei.InstanceID
 from EA E ei, INVITE i, osttable ost, ef e
 where ei.Finished is not null
       and ei.InviteID = i.InviteID
```

What is the cause for my error?

PS I've changed table names for privacy reasons so don't worry if they don't match up.

Comment: You have a whole load of CROSS JOINs there. Does this work, even with the subquery thing fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Firstname, Lastname, ei.Started, 
          ((ei.totalcorrect*100)/@examQuestionCount) as percentage,
           passed_ = CASE Passed
                WHEN '1' THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No'
           END,
     ei.InstanceID
 from EA E ei, INVITE i, osttable ost, ef e
 where ei.Finished is not null
       and ei.InviteID = i.InviteID
```

Answer (score 2):

A subquery in that position is expected to return no more than one value (i.e. one column in one row), but your subquery returns two columns (one is `Passed`, the other is an unnamed column represented by the CASE expression) and I cannot know how many rows.

You should either integrate the results of the subquery into your main query (something along the lines of what @Alex_L is suggesting) or limit the subquery's output to the expected quantity of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [IAS_AccountDB]
GO
/* Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Prc_Accounts_LastNodes]    Script Date: 04/01/2013 01:29:20 */
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prc_Accounts_LastNodes]
(
    @AccountParentID int = NULL
)
AS
SELECT 
    [Accounts].[AccountName] 
    ,[Accounts].[AccountID] 
FROM
    [Accounts] 
WHERE
    @AccountParentID IN
    (
        SELECT
            [Accounts].[AccountID]
            ,[Accounts].[AccountName]
            ,[Accounts].[AccountStandardCode]
        FROM     
            [Accounts]
        WHERE
         NOT EXISTS
         (
            SELECT TOP 1
                1
            FROM
                [Accounts_ParentIDs]
            WHERE
                [Accounts_ParentIDs].[AccountParentID] =  [Accounts].[AccountID] 
         )


    ) 

RETURN 0;
```

Comment: A code or SQL only answer is seldom a good answer. You should also consider adding some explanatory text to your answer.